# Firefox blocking Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, firefox

I changed settings of Windows firewall to block public and private networks to test Postgres installation in  Windows 7, then I changed it back to default settings which allow both networks.  However, when I access Stack Overflow site using Firefox 3.6.18 ,I am getting this message(inside a red ribbon)

> Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.

However, Javascript is not blocked when IE or Chrome are used.  I checked the `options-content` tab and it has Javascript enabled.  So, I guess this is a problem with Firefox.
To add to confusion,I am able to use scripts on http://www.decatur.de/javascript/dew/index.html using Firefox!

I have NoScript installed on Firefox.But I have set `"Allow all this page"` for this site. Even when I allowed "Allow scripts globally" I am getting this message.
Any idea how to set this right?

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow requires jQuery which is loaded via Google's CDN, residing on ajax.googleapis.com - so you will have to whitelist that.

In addition, Stack Overflow also makes use of scripts from sstatic.net, you make sure that's whitelisted as well.